# What would be the best algorithm to predict stress level according to the heart rate?

Tags: algorithms, regression, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have developed IOT device that can read heart rate from the human body.
So now i want to predict **Stress Level** with continuouse value.
Attributes/features will be **Heart Rate, Age and the Time**
What would be the best algorithm to predict stress levels? need your help.

Comment: It would be better if a regression model has been set up and you ask a question on this concrete model. The current question seems too broad.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer.
Can i do this with gradient decent algorithm under regression?
I think gradient decen allows us to use multiple parameters right?

Comment: Do you mean the gradient method for solving systems of equations? Honestly, I don't see how it connects to establishing a regression model.

Comment: As Alex said, the gradient descent method is not a regression algorithm but rather an algorithm meant to find optimum solutions to a particular equation (system of equations).
In other terms, once you have some kind of equation (as simple as a linear regression with two parameters a and b, or more complex like a full neural network system with a big weight matrix) and you want to find which set of parameters give you the best approximations/values, then you can use the gradient descent method to find this set of optimal parameters.